# Comparable Topologies on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, projection

Let $A$ be the set obtained by removing the set $$Y:=\{(0, y)\ |\ y\neq 0\}$$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Clearly, the set $Y$ is the $y$-axis minus the origin. Let $$\tau_1: \text{subspace topology on A induced from the usual topology of}\ \mathbb{R}^2.$$ Let $$\tau_2:\ \text{quotient topology on A due to the following surjective map}\ \Phi ,$$ where
$$\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to A$$ defined by $$\Phi(x, y)= (x, y)\ \text{for}\ x\neq 0, \ \text{and}\ \Phi(0, y)= (0, 0)\ \text{for all}\ y.$$
Let $\tau_2$ be the resulting quotient topology on $A$.

I need to show that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are comparable.

My thought: I want to show that either $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$ or $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$. I know that, by definition, a set $V$ is open in $\tau_1$ if $V=W\cap A$, where $W$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Further, by definition, $\tau_2$ is the smallest topology such that $\Phi$ is continuous. How to use these to show the result.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: $Y$ is not the $y$ axis because the origin is left over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not the same topologies.

Let $U\subset A$ the open ball of radius one around the origin. This is the open ball with the non origin points of the $y$ axis missing. It can be expressed as the intersection of $U$ and $B_1(0,0)=\{x:\lvert x\rvert\lt 1\}$ so $U$ is open under the subspace topology.

But $\Phi^{-1}(U)=B_1(0,0)\cup Y$ which is not open in $\mathbb R^2$ so $U$ is not open in the quotient topology.

Comment: This means that subspace topology is not contained in the quotient topology. Can you please look at the other way around?

Comment: @AGIRI The only thing for you to do for that case is to look at open sets containing the origin. The $y$ axis in $\mathbb R^2$ must be in the preimage which means the only open sets containing the origin are open vertical strips. Those are also open in the subspace topology and and the open sets not containing the origin are identical in both topologies.